# Why switch inside foreach loop executes only once

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, switch-statement

on debugging I have a condition where `Component.Attributes` consists has Count =3 (i mean list of 3 elements).
And it's Inside foreach loop like this:

```
foreach(Attributes atrb in Component.Attributes) 
{
    switch (Component.Type)
    {
        case "Combo":
            return validateCombo(atrb);
        case "List":
            return validateList(atrb);
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

I observe that this foreach loop executes for the first member of list only. Could someone please let me know why it ddo not execute for other list members (i mean at count 2 and 3) ? IS it due to return . How to solve it ?

Comment: Step through this code with a debugger.

Comment: Because there's a return statement on each case...

Comment: Use break instead of return in your `cases`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Return` is an end of function statement. Upon reaching the first `return` statement, your whole function is terminated, thus the loop ends immediately.

You will typically want to use the `break` statement between different switch cases to stop the execution from continuing until the end of the switch definition.